# How to change default URL in Django Photologue

Tags: django, django-urls, photologue

Is it possible to change default URL in Photologue? For example this URL

`url(r'^photo/(?P<slug>[\-\d\w]+)/$', PhotoDetailView.as_view(), name='pl-photo')`

I want to change on

`url(r'^pictures/(?P<slug>[\-\d\w]+)/$', PhotoDetailView.as_view(), name='pl-photo')`

In documentation I find only example how to override URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very elegant solution, but it will work:

In your project's urls.py file, you have already included Photologue's urls:

```
url(r'^photologue/', include('photologue.urls', namespace='photologue')),
```

What you can do is write a *custom* urls.py file, in which you copy-and-paste Photologue's urls.py file - but then you change 'photo' to be pictures.

*Note:* remember to change the `import` at the top to `from photologue.views import ...`.

Then include your custom urls.py file *in place of* including the standard Photologue urls.py file.

**Note:** it's not a very elegant solution because you are duplicating code - and if you ever upgrade the Photologue version used in your project, you will need to check if the urls.py file has changed.

Comment: funny, I made the same thing that you wrote, but don't closed this question because think that someone knows more interesting solution :)